# How to change my multi-class training to binary in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, classification, multiclass-classification

I'm new to Deep Learning and `Keras`. With my simple training code below, I was classifying 10 classes. But now I want to re-use this code and convert this code to binary case where I say if an image is my object or not.

I tried to change the activation from `softmax` to `sigmoid`, and also changed updated `loss='binary_crossentropy'`. Is this enough to change? Any other changes?

I get an error saying:

```
  File "train.py", line 94, in <module>
    shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1732, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 260, in fit_generator
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/callbacks/callbacks.py", line 152, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/callbacks/callbacks.py", line 702, in on_epoch_end
    filepath = self.filepath.format(epoch=epoch + 1, **logs)
KeyError: 'acc'
```

Here is my simple training code for multi-class classification:

```
#==========================
HEIGHT = 300
WIDTH = 300
TRAIN_DIR = "data"
BATCH_SIZE = 8 #8
steps_per_epoch = 1000 #1000
NUM_EPOCHS = 50 #50
lr= 0.00001
#==========================
FC_LAYERS = [1024, 1024]
dropout = 0.5

def build_finetune_model(base_model, dropout, fc_layers, num_classes):
    for layer in base_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    x = base_model.output
    x = Flatten()(x)
    for fc in fc_layers:
        # New FC layer, random init
        x = Dense(fc, activation='relu')(x) 
        x = Dropout(dropout)(x)

    # New softmax layer
    predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x) 
    finetune_model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
    return finetune_model

train_datagen =  ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_DIR, 
                                                    target_size=(HEIGHT, WIDTH), 
                                                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
base_model = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3))

root=TRAIN_DIR
class_list = [ item for item in os.listdir(root) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, item)) ]
print (class_list)

FC_LAYERS = [1024, 1024]
dropout = 0.5

finetune_model = build_finetune_model(base_model, dropout=dropout, fc_layers=FC_LAYERS, num_classes=len(class_list))
adam = Adam(lr=0.00001)
finetune_model.compile(adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
filepath="./checkpoints/" + "MobileNetV2_{epoch:02d}_{acc:.2f}" +"_model_weights.h5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor=["acc"], verbose=1, mode='max', save_weights_only=True)
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

history = finetune_model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, workers=8, 
                                       steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, 
                                       shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should have only one output node, since it will have the probability of the class (hence 1 - that is the probability of not having that class).

Changing the activation to `sigmoid` is correct, since you want to work with a conditional type of probability output, instead of a join probability.

Binary cross-entropy is correct to apply, since you are dealing with binary target data.

Finally, the error seems to be the keyword you are passing in `monitor`. Try replacing it with `monitor= "val_accuracy"`.

Comment: Thanks. But I was using the same keyword before for multi-class. Why should I change it now?

Comment: @TinaJ presumably it should match the keyword you are giving when you compile the model, which is `metrics=['accuracy']`

Comment: Well, I compile with `accuracy` and monitor `acc`. So it has problems?

Comment: + another question is why saving the model takes so long time? The whole epochs is like 30min, but the last epoch (saving) takes 3 hours!

Comment: I am not too sure, but I assume it might have something to do, with the checkpoints saving only the model's weight, whereas the the last epoch compiles the model and saves the full path? I'm trying to find more information on the topic.

Comment: As for accuracy, I believe the issue arises from the fact you need to specify validation, hence you can either choose between val_accuracy and val_loss (in this case where you compiled the model with metrics=['accuracy'] as The Guy with The Hat said.

Comment: Thanks. I've made your change `monitor= "val_accuracy"` and let's see!

Comment: I also added my training values.

Comment: Can you answe my new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58919494/my-simple-keras-prediction-shows-wrong-prediction

Comment: I'll look into it in a few mins